# Using self-compiled Roslyn from within Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

Is there a way to configure Visual Studio such that it uses my own self-compiled / self-built (forked) version of the .NET Compiler Platform (Roslyn)?

I want to experiement with C# language extensions in a convenient way.

(I am aware of the fact that this is [not an officially supported scenario](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Building-Testing-and-Debugging#deploying-and-testing-within-visual-studio) as of now. Still, I consider it an interesting playground scenario for the community)

Comment: FWIW, for the CTP for 2013, there have been instructions for it: [Taking a tour of Roslyn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/04/03/taking-a-tour-of-roslyn.aspx), search for "ADVANCED USAGE". But those instructions likely won't work for the current version of Roslyn or for Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: The below answer is deleted now but there was a very important comment left under it by Jason Malinowski: "*If all goes well, we should have proper support for this coming in the next month or so.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With VS2015 Update 1 (which will be available any day now) you will be able to build your Roslyn solution, set "VisualStudioSetup" as your startup project, and just run it. That will run an instance of Visual Studio with the just-built Roslyn substituted for the one built in to VS2015.

Comment: It's time: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/11/30/what-s-new-in-visual-studio-update-1-for-net-managed-languages.aspx see also updated https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Building-Testing-and-Debugging

Answer (score 1):

See this [article](http://www.sebbylive.com/articles/programming/aspect_oriented_programming_roslyn.aspx) that give an example of using modified Roslyn compiler for manipulate the code when compiling